# Selenium - click on property, second div with a classname by text

Tags: javascript, css, selenium, xpath, protractor

I need to click on property by name Émilie's Castle location, 
but I can not locate by text the name:

```
<div class="text capitalize">
      <div class="name truncate">Émilie's Castle location</div>
```

In selenium ide it works:

`css=div.name.truncate:contains(Émilie's Castle location)`

In protractor I try to use this line of code but it doesn't work:

`element(by.className('name truncate')).click();`

I can not use classname because all properties have the same name of class:

`<div class="name truncate">`

How to locate by text in webdriver and protractor?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code, it should work:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('.name.truncate', 'Émilie's Castle location')).click();
```

Comment: This will work perfectly. [See here the API-Description](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText)

Comment: @Rakesh Thanks,yes it works:  element(by.cssContainingText('.name','Émilie\'s Castle location')).click();

Comment: @Lelik_ Cool..Please accept the solution